# Using FBML in a ruby sinatra app

Tags: ruby, facebook, sinatra, fbml

I'm building an application in ruby using the sinatra framework and am having trouble with rendering some fbml elements.

I'm currently trying to render an fb:multi-friend-selector so the user can select which friends they want to invite. However, when I write the following in my code:

```
<fb:fbml> 
    <fb:request-form action="/inviteFriends" method="POST" invite="true" type="MY APP" content="Invite Friends" > 
         <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" actiontext="Invite your friends to use YOUR APP NAME."> 
    </fb:request-form> 
</fb:fbml>
```

Nothing renders with the text above. I've included the regular facebook xsds for the taglibs in my html tag and have tested fbml on the page using the following code:

```
<fb:name useyou="false" uid="USER_ID" linked="false"/>
```

This code works correctly and displays the user's name.

I've tried a simple example like that on http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:random but again nothing is rendered in the browser.

Do I need to include some special javascript or anything?

I would greatly appreciate some help with this.

Thanks in advance
-gearoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just realised that you have to use the server:fbml tags for this to work.

Facebook documentation could really use some work :)